# Android Navigation View Item clicks only once

Tags: java, android, xml, drawerlayout, navigationview

i am having a serious weird bug in android navigation view item click, the items are only clicking once when you open the app and stops clicking after, but the weirdest part is that the item is responding to click at the edge every time.

Below is my main xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/layout_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:theme="@style/NavigationView"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/black"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/black"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Navigation menu items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:checked="true"
            android:id="@+id/home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="@string/home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/latest"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_latest"
            android:title="@string/latest" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/category"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_category"
            android:title="@string/category" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

The layout Frame

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/toolbar"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frame_one"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My Activity code

```
package com.education.books.MySchoolLibrary;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class NewAct extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    public Toolbar toolbar;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private NavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Tool");

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        this.navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        View headerview = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

        findViewById(R.id.frame_one).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Toast.makeText(this, "frame ti ya werey!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        drawer.closeDrawers();

        if (id == R.id.home) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.latest) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.category) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

But if i copy this whole code into an entirely new application, it is working fine, pls i don't know what i am doing wrong. Thanks.

[image: A picture of the edge where the item is getting clicked, but not getting clicked on the main item area.]

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issue.found a work around solution like below

```
  nav_view.menu.findItem(R.id.menu_share).setOnMenuItemClickListener {
        shareApp()
        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        true
    }
```